# Content of /etc/network in Alpine Linux image

Tags: networking, docker, network-interface, alpine-linux

I have an Alpine Linux image installed on a docker container. I was exploring it, and doing `ls -lR /etc/network` I had this result:

```
/etc/network/:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16  2020 if-down.d
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16  2020 if-post-down.d
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16  2020 if-post-up.d
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16  2020 if-pre-down.d
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16  2020 if-pre-up.d
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16  2020 if-up.d
/etc/network/if-down.d:
total 0
/etc/network/if-post-down.d:
total 0
/etc/network/if-post-up.d:
total 0
/etc/network/if-pre-down.d:
total 0
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d:
total 0
/etc/network/if-up.d:
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root           218 Jan 15  2020 dad
```

Inside `/etc/network/if-up.d/dad` I found:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Block ifup until DAD completion
# Copyright (c) 2016-2018 Kaarle Ritvanen
has_flag() {
    ip address show dev $IFACE | grep -q \" $1 \"
}
while has_flag tentative && ! has_flag dadfailed; do
    sleep 0.2
done
```

I'm trying to understand why those folders exist and which is the purpose of `dad`. I searched on internet, but I didn't find anything useful. I expected to find something like /etc/network/interfaces, but I can't understand what's the purpose of this all. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: `dad`  is duplicate address detection in IPv6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those folders are hooks for ifupdown, there are a lot ifupdown implementation, but alpine default one is busybox's, you can check the source here [networking/ifupdown.c](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/mirror/busybox/-/blob/networking/ifupdown.c).

busybox only handle `auto` interface, support these builtin types.

- inet

  - manual wvdial ppp static bootp dhcp loopback
- inet6

  - static manual loopback v4tunnel

ifupdown has two $MODE (`up` and`down`), for each mode, has two hook: `pre-` and `post-`.

Folders contain the hook script will called by `run-parts`, check the [code process](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/mirror/busybox/-/blob/networking/ifupdown.c?subtree=true#L1211).

You can use the hook to implement extra type, to make config easier, like `bonding` provided by [bonding](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=bonding&arch=x86_64&repo=main) package. All existing script is [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=%2Fetc%2Fnetwork%2F*&name=&branch=edge&arch=x86_64).

[dad](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7527) is provided by busybox for IPv6 Enhanced Duplicate Address Detection.